# Contradictions when implementing FIFO Priority Queue in Python

Tags: python, fifo, heapq

For a school assignment, I am tasked with implementing a FIFO Priority Queue using heapq.  I am using a counter when appending which tracks when a node was pushed onto the heap.  However, in the unit tests we must pass there seems to be a contradiction of sorts:

1. In the first test, it pushes tuples (an integer and a string) to the priority queue.  The integer value is also pushed onto a temporary list.  The temp list is then sorted in ascending order and the test begins to pop off our queue elements.  They are looking for the two values to match.  If the temp list is (1, 2, 5, 6) for example, the first element to pop off the pq should be 1.  I was able to get this test to pass fairly easily.
2. However, test 2 tests for FIFO functionality.  Essentially, elements with equal integer values should be popped off in the order added.  This is where I implemented a counter to keep track of added orders and the FIFO test passed.  However, the first test now fails.  It seems contradictory to expect the heap to pop off elements by minimum tuple integer value instead of priority.  Am I misthinking this issue?  I cannot, unfortunately, post any code as my program doesn't allow us to post raw code on StackOverflow.  I've been stuck trying to figure out this basic implementation for several days.

Comment: You could use the integer value, then only use insertion order as a tiebreak, no? e.g. each element could have the tuple (int, insertion_order) associated with it, where int is the integer given and insertion_order is the number of elements in the heap at the time the element was inserted. Python's normal ordering of tuples will sort those correctly. E.g. the tuple (1, 0) is less than (1, 1).

Comment: See also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes

Comment: *"I cannot, unfortunately, post any code"*: noone can forbid you to post code on Stack Overflow. What can be forbidden is that you post content that isn't yours, like information given in an assignment, including template code, custom libraries, .... But thousands have gone before you in posting code concerning priority queues, with similar requirements, so you wouldn't reveal anything special; nothing that would be secret. Just use different inputs, and show your work (only).

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example"). We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.